# how to send data from a form on one page to a different form on a different page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a form where the user can fill out for any enquiries related to the product. I want to get the information the user has filled out and send it to a new page when the user clicks submit, showing them a summary of what they have written and then to submit their enquiry. Below you are able to see my code and what I am trying to achieve.

enquiry.html:

```
<form method="GET" action="final.html" id="myform" class="contact-form">
<label id="fullname">Full Name*</label> <br />
<input name="name" id="name" class="txt-form name" type="text" />

<label id="mail">Email*</label> <br />
<input name="email" id="email" class="txt-form email" type="email" />

<label id="cheap">Have you found this item cheaper on a competitor website?*</label><br />

<label>
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
<label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span>Yes</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
<label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span>No</label> <br />
</label>

<div id="url">
      <label>Competitor URL</label>
      <input name="url_name" id="url-link" class="txt-form" type="url">
</div>

<label id="msg">Enquiry Message* <span id="characters">(0/200)</span></label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" class="txt-form message"type="textarea"></textarea>
<p id="asterisk">Fields marked with an *asterisk are compulsory</p>
<input type="submit" class=" btn" id="submit" value="Submit your enquiry">
</form>
```

summary.html:

```
<div id="app" class="contact-main">
<form id="myform" class="contact-form">
</form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = `
<label>Full Name: </label>
<br /><br />

<label>Email:</label> <br /><br />

<label>Size of item selected:</label> <br /><br />

<label>Have you found this item cheaper on a competitor
    website?
</label><br /><br />

<div>
    <label>Competitor URL:</label> <br /><br />
</div>

<label id="msg">Enquiry Message</label><br /><br />
`;
```

As you can see above, I have 2 HTML files. The enquiry.html includes the form where the user can fill out the information and the summary.html includes a blank form which gets filled out via javascript. I want the information entered in the enquiry.html form to be sent to the summary.html form.

I am kind of new to PHP so if anyone can explain how to go about doing this, it'll be very helpful.

Comment: PS: Never give name or ID "submit" to a form field. It will block you from ever submitting using script

Comment: i can see you closed my question. Can I ask the reason behind it because I've been looking everywhere and cant seem to find a good explanation on what my issue is.

Comment: 1. Using php change the .html to php and read the form content using the $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST

Comment: 2. Using JavaScript, you can use AJAX to read summary into enquiry.html and fill it with the form content

Comment: Please see the results of the two searches I posted for you. There WILL be several of those which could fit your issue.

Comment: Why do you have a form in summary? Also you need to add the variables passed: `document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = \`
<label>Full Name: </label> ${name}....
<br /><br />`

Comment: You can get the [vars from the URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams): `const url = new URL(location.href); const name = url.searchParams.get("name"); `

Comment: I have been looking through the results, they don't seem to fit my issue. 

I have a form in summary so the labels can be displayed on screen and then next to each label will be the value from the previous form the user has submitted. 

I don't have the best knowledge in PHP, hence why I needed someone to more or less clarify each step for me, so in the future I no what to do if I ever come across something like this...

Comment: So the answer is pure JS since you do not seem to have a PHP summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a form in summary?

Also you need to add the variables passed:

```
document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = ` <label>Full Name: </label> ${name}.... <br /><br />
```

You can get the vars from the URL:

```
const url = new URL(location.href); 
const name = url.searchParams.get("name");
```

Example

```js
// ignore this line
var serialize = function (form) { var arr = []; Array.prototype.slice.call(form.elements).forEach(function (field) { if (!field.name || field.disabled || ['file', 'reset', 'submit', 'button'].indexOf(field.type) > -1) return; if (field.type === 'select-multiple') { Array.prototype.slice.call(field.options).forEach(function (option) { if (!option.selected) return; arr.push(encodeURIComponent(field.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(option.value)); }); return; } if (['checkbox', 'radio'].indexOf(field.type) >-1 && !field.checked) return; arr.push(encodeURIComponent(field.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(field.value)); }); return arr.join('&'); };

window.addEventListener("load",function() { // important on summary.html too

   // ------ remove from here
  document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", function(e) { // faking a submission for testing purposes
    e.preventDefault(); // remove on summary.html
    const url = new URL(this.action+"?"+serialize(this)); // to pretend to get the url from the form on the next page - remove from summary.html
   // ------ to here

  // code on summary.html
  // const url = new URL(location.href); // uncomment in summary.html




    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = `
<label>Full Name: </label> ${url.searchParams.get("name") || "N/A"}
<br /><br />

<label>Email:</label> ${url.searchParams.get("email") || "N/A"}<br /><br />

<label>Size of item selected:</label> ${url.searchParams.get("size") || "N/A"} <br /><br />

<label>Have you found this item cheaper on a competitor
    website?
</label> ${url.searchParams.get("radio") || "N/A" } <br /><br />

<div>
    <label>Competitor URL:</label> ${url.searchParams.get("url-link") || "N/A"} <br /><br />
</div>

<label id="msg">Enquiry Message</label> ${url.searchParams.get("message") || "N/A"} <br /><br />
`;

  }); // remove from summary.html
}); // keep on summary.html
```

```html
<form method="GET" action="final.html" id="myform" class="contact-form">
  <label id="fullname">Full Name*</label> <br />
  <input name="name" id="name" class="txt-form name" type="text" />

  <label id="mail">Email*</label> <br />
  <input name="email" id="email" class="txt-form email" type="email" />

  <label id="cheap">Have you found this item cheaper on a competitor website?*</label><br />

  <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
  <label for="radio1">Yes</label>
  <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
  <label for="radio2">No</label> <br />


  <div id="url">
    <label>Competitor URL</label>
    <input name="url_name" id="url-link" class="txt-form" type="url">
  </div>

  <label id="msg">Enquiry Message* <span id="characters">(0/200)</span></label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="txt-form message" type="textarea"></textarea>
  <p id="asterisk">Fields marked with an *asterisk are compulsory</p>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit your enquiry">
</form>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: when i add the variables passed, nothing seems to happen

Comment: See update. Complicated to show functionality when I only have one page